# Android app: How do I make my app show up in audio output suggestions

Tags: java, android, react-native, nativeapplication

Example: When I click on attach audio button, I want my app to show in apps suggestion(along with sound recorder).

Answer (score 1):

I  assume that you could solve your problem by defining `<intent-filter>`s in Manifest File. Your filter for audio files could be something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="content"/>
    <data android:scheme="file"/>
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

For more in-depth knowledge you can refer to [Official Android Documentation.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I will refer the link and your proposed solution and post it here it it works.